# Remote Desktop Client in C# to access image data

Tags: c#, .net, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm trying to establish an RDP connection to some remote host using C#. I need to access the image data directly for further processing (convert them to DirectX Textures). All examples I can find deal with WPF/ActiveX to display the RPD session in its own window, though. I don't want the window and the additional dependencies in my project, just direct access to the image data in real-time. Is there some, preferably straight-forward, way to do this?